# Neo4J path subquery for versioned nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXgAn.png) (sorry you need to click the image)

I have a graph with two kinds of nodes:

- **identity-nodes** as structural elements (blue) holding no attributes
- versioned **value-nodes** which hold attributes/data (orange)

There are two relation kinds:

- **version-of**: connects value-nodes to identity-nodes and contains a window within which the relation shall be valid (picture shows just a start date)
- **parent-of**: connects identity-nodes in a hierarchical fashion

Scenario:

- There is at most one valid value-node per identity-node at any given time.
- I want to keep historical values and look back any time, so copying the values that are currently valid to the respective identity-nodes will not work.
- Hierarchy can be of arbitrary depth, say 1 to 10.
- I wan't to search using fully qualified paths-strings from root to leaf using an attribute of a value-node.
- I want to find the path along ID nodes as well as the right value-of at the end of the path. (Think of a file-system directory path.)

In this example I'm searching for a path "A/CD/E" where A CD E are values of the name property of value-nodes. Basically I want to find the right 'E' node, here the one that is associated to 98. Time is ommited from the examples below to keep them short.

How do I do that? Is that even possible using only Neo4J? (It's easily done wrapping the query in another script that generates a path match including a named id node for each path entry.)

I can query for start and end of the path to limit the search space, but what about **a variable number of nodes** in between? In a manner of thinking ID nodes would have to be merged with their values matching the time window on the version-of relation before each query.

```
MATCH p=(start:value) -[:`version-of`]-> (:ID) <-[:`parent-of`*]- (:ID) <-[:`version-of`]- (end:value)
WHERE start.name = 'A' AND end.name = 'E'
RETURN p
```

What I would like to ask (using variable depth keys instead of the short example); the following is not valid cypher:

```
MATCH p=(start:value) -[:`version-of`]-> (:ID) <-[:`parent-of`*]- (:ID) <-[:`version-of`]- (end:value)
WHERE p = 'A/CD/E' // or something longer, "A/CD/E/F/X"
RETURN p, end
```

### What I've looked at so far

I can also build the list of names along the path and compare the full paths against the query string. But it can't get the name value for the nodes between start and end:

```
MATCH p=(start:value) -[:`version-of`]-> (:ID) <-[:`parent-of`*]- (:ID) <-[:`version-of`]- (end:value)
WHERE start.name = 'A' AND end.name = 'E'
RETURN EXTRACT(n in nodes(p)|n['name'])
```

Subgraph relevant for the query in pairs, but missing the path. Can I get a path of id,val pairs here somehow?

```
MATCH p=(start:value) -[:`version-of`]-> (:ID) <-[:`parent-of`*]- (:ID) <-[:`version-of`]- (end:value)
WHERE start.name = 'A' AND end.name = 'E'
UNWIND nodes(p) as id
MATCH (id) <-[:`version-of`]- (val)
RETURN COLLECT([id,val])
```

### Here's the graph

```
MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n
CREATE (:value {name:'A'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-01-01'}]-> (:ID {id:32})
CREATE (:value {name:'CC'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-01-05'}]-> (:ID {id:21})
CREATE (:value {name:'E'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-02-01'}]-> (:ID {id:98})
CREATE (:value {name:'E'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-02-01'}]-> (:ID {id:48})
MATCH (n:ID {id:21}) CREATE (:value {name:'CD'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-03-01'}]-> (n)
MATCH (a:ID {id:32}),(b:ID {id:21}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b)
MATCH (a:ID {id:21}),(b:ID {id:98}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b)
MATCH (a:ID {id:32}),(b:ID {id:48}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b)
```

Comment: Nothing is clear. Show the expected results on these test data.

Comment: It's right there on a pseudo-code piece titled "What I would like to ask". I hope I managed to make it more clear in the text as well now.

Comment: In your graph creation cypher, you have two identical rows between a value 'E' and :ID 48. I'm guessing one of those can be removed?

Comment: indeed. removed, copy+paste mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close!

Your last query, with the id/val pairs, is missing the path because you're collecting without any context:

```
RETURN COLLECT([id,val])
```

This is just asking for one single collection of id/val pairs. If you want the collection of id/val pairs for each path, you need to have the path variable `p` as a non-aggregation field, which will act as a grouping key for your aggregation:

```
WITH p, COLLECT([id,val]) as pairs  // one collection per path
RETURN pairs
```

As for making sure CD is in the path, we need to find CD's :ID node, and add a predicate to ensure that this node is on the path:

```
MATCH (:value{name:'CD'})-[:`version-of`]->(cdID:ID)
MATCH p=(start:value) -[:`version-of`]-> (:ID) <-[:`parent-of`*]- (:ID) <-[:`version-of`]- (end:value)
WHERE start.name = 'A' AND end.name = 'E' AND cdID in nodes(p)
UNWIND nodes(p)[1..-1] as id
MATCH (id) <-[:`version-of`]- (val)
WITH p, COLLECT([id,val]) as pairs
RETURN pairs
```

EDIT

Clarified requirements now include specifying the names of :value nodes associated with whichever :IDs should be along the path, presumably in order.

Let's see if this one will work. I'll use your existing graph (removing the duplicate E-for-id-48 line), and just for this example we'll omit the direction of the :parent-of relationship, since with the existing direction we don't have enough nodes to have more than one element in the intermediate path. Let's go from E to E, requiring the IDs for the following value nodes in order: 'E', 'A', 'CD', 'E'. With our graph we expect to get a single path of the following :IDs associated with the value names: 48, 32, 21, 98

This is going to be a complex query, as dealing with indices isn't so straight forward in Cypher. It's also a query where we filter all possible paths, as I can't see a way to filter during expansion:

```
WITH ['E', 'A', 'CD', 'E'] as names
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(names)-1) as index
WITH index, names[index] as name
// each name with its expected index in the path

MATCH (:value{name:name})-[:`version-of`]->(id:ID)
WITH index, name, COLLECT(id) as ids
ORDER BY index ASC
WITH COLLECT({name:name, ids:ids}) as pathdef
// index-order collection of expected name and possible IDs for the name

MATCH p=(start:value) -[:`version-of`]-> (:ID) -[:`parent-of`*]- (:ID) <-[:`version-of`]- (end:value)
WHERE start.name = 'E' AND end.name = 'E' AND LENGTH(p)-1 = SIZE(pathdef)
// we have all paths from E to E of the desired length

// only interested in :ID nodes in match, leave off :value nodes at end
WITH pathdef, NODES(p)[1..-1] as nodes, RANGE(0, SIZE(pathdef)-1) as indices
// due to our match from start and end values, don't need to check start/end :ID nodes
WHERE ALL(index in indices[1..-1] WHERE nodes[index] in pathdef[index].ids)
// we've filtered to only path nodes associated with values in expected order
UNWIND indices as index
RETURN COLLECT([nodes[index], pathdef[index].name]) as pairs
```

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed an aprroach I didn't look at.
But this works only for the example with a single node between A und E, but doesn't work for an arbitrary number of nodes in between because it just checks for X in nodes(p). It neither checks nodes in between in order and also could find the same id more than once.

Comment: So you need to support checking of multiple nodes in the path, and you need to ensure order of those nodes in the path, and the same node id can't occur more than once? Please add those new requirements to your description, it's hard to give good answers without knowing about them.

Comment: Added a query that should fulfill your requirements. There may still be some ways to optimize, however.

Comment: Wow, you're a wizard with cyper! I guess they would have to add something join-like to neo4j to do this in a "pretty" and short way.

Comment: It's a rather specific case, but I think there may be room for something to shortcut the index and unwind operations. Make sure you add back the `parent-of` relationship direction if you're going to use the query!

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;
CREATE (:value {name:'A'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-01-01'}]-> (:ID {id:32});
CREATE (:value {name:'CC'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-01-05'}]-> (:ID {id:21});
CREATE (:value {name:'E'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-02-01'}]-> (:ID {id:98});
CREATE (:value {name:'N'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-02-01'}]-> (:ID {id:87});
CREATE (:value {name:'E'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-02-01'}]-> (:ID {id:48});
CREATE (:value {name:'W'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-02-01'}]-> (:ID {id:74});
CREATE (:value {name:'E'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-01-01'}]-> (:ID {id:75});
MATCH (n:ID {id:21}) CREATE (:value {name:'CD'}) -[:`version-of` {from:'2017-03-01'}]-> (n);
MATCH (a:ID {id:32}),(b:ID {id:21}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b);
MATCH (a:ID {id:32}),(b:ID {id:23}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b);
MATCH (a:ID {id:32}),(b:ID {id:48}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b);
MATCH (a:ID {id:48}),(b:ID {id:87}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b);
MATCH (a:ID {id:87}),(b:ID {id:98}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b);
MATCH (a:ID {id:21}),(b:ID {id:74}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b);
MATCH (a:ID {id:74}),(b:ID {id:75}) CREATE (a)<-[:`parent-of`]-(b);
```

[a more exiting example-graph to test on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsk1U.png)
(solution above works here, too)